# transform xaml to code c# in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, charts

Hy Everybody!! I want to transform my xaml to code c# but i don't know how to add my LinearSeries to my chart;
My xaml is below:

```
<chartingToolkit:Chart Height="369"  Name="lineChart" Title="500 Premiers valeurs"
        Width="608" Margin="158,97,12,95" Visibility="Hidden">
    <chartingToolkit:LineSeries  DependentValuePath="Value" IndependentValuePath="Key"
        ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    </chartingToolkit:LineSeries>
</chartingToolkit:Chart>
```

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lineChart.Series` is a required property. The setter is inaccessible, so you need to use `Add()` method:

```
lineChart.Series.Add(new LineSeries());
```

Nested elements are contained in a property defined by `ContentProperty` attribute. You can check your metadata using Visual Studio or open a source code (the source of Chart control is [here](http://wpf.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Toolkit-release/DataVisualization/Charting/Chart/Chart.cs)).

Comment: thank you for your answer, but when i use linechart.Series.Add(new LinearSeries()); i have this error No suitable axis is available for plotting the dependent value.

Comment: You need to create LinearSeries object first.
var series = new LinearSeries()
{ // }; lineChart.Series.Add(series); Don't forget to accept my answer.